Cyclic Permutations Mapping Formula Reference Request

A permutation which shifts all elements of a set by a fixed offset,
with the elements shifted off the end inserted back at the beginning.
For a set with elements $a_0, a_1,...,a_{n-1}$ ... a cyclic permutation of one
place to the right would yield $a_{n-1}, a_0,a_1,...$
The mapping can be
written as $a_i \rightarrow a_{i+k \ (mod \ n)}$ for a shift of $k$ places to the right.

Weisstein, Eric W. "Cyclic Permutation." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicPermutation.html
Does anyone know of an academic paper or textbook that explicitly states or justifies this mapping formula? I understand that it’s a standard definition, but I want to cite a reliable resource for thoroughness and clarity since it forms the foundation for some of my arguments.
So far, I have searched through abstract algebra texts under topics like cyclic groups, permutation groups, and dihedral groups without success. Am I exploring the correct field for this?

"Does anyone know of a paper or textbook that explicitly states or justifies this mapping formula?"  The Weisstein post stated the permutation explicitly, and it is irrelevant or meaningless to "justify" it.  What can you mean by "justify"?

By "justify" I mean a work that proves it. Why is it meaningless to "justify" it?

Maybe I needed to clarify that I'm specifically looking for a citable academic source that formally presents the formula, rather than a web resource.

I suggest adding the [tag:reference-request] tag since you're looking for a formal definition within a textbook or the like. And perhaps make the title clearer about that as well.

It makes no sense to try to "prove" a permutation.  Every book on discrete group theory talks about permutations.  You cannot "prove" an operation.  You prove a PROPOSITION.
